# F# Traversing mutually recursive tree to count elements

Tags: f#, tree

Given the following types:

```
type Title    = string
type Document = Title * Element list
and Element   = Par of string | Sec of Document
```

I'm attempting to create a function which will traverse the tree and count the number of occurrences of `Sec`.

Given the following example:

```
let s1  = ("section 1", [Par "Bla"])
let s2  = ("section 2", [Sec s21; Par "Bla"])
let s21 = ("subsection 2.1", [Par "Bla"])
let s3  = ("section 3", [Par "Bla"])
let doc = ("Compiler project", [Par "Bla"; Sec s1; Sec s2; Sec s3]);
```

A function taking a `Document` to count number of `Sections`, `noOfSecs d` would in this case return `4`, as there are `4` `Sections` in this case. I've attempted something, but I'm a little stuck, especially what to do when I hit a `Par`:

```
let rec noOfSecs d =
    match d with
    | (_,[])    -> 0
    | (_,e::es) -> (findSecs e)
and findSecs = function
    | Sec(t,_::es) -> 1 + noOfSecs (t,es)
    | Par p        -> //What should we do here?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 0 `Sec`s within a `Par string` so you can return 0 for that case. In `noOfSecs` you need to sum the `Sec` cases for each element in the element list, not just the first one. You can use `List.sumBy` for this:

```
let rec noOfSecs (_, elems) =
    List.sumBy findSecs elems
and findSecs = function
    | Sec d -> 1 + noOfSecs d
    | Par p        -> 0
```